# UIPageViewController with a slide out table view

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

Hi there I've messed around with a few different ways on implementing this but can't seem to make anything work. What I'm looking to do is have a standard UIPageViewcontroller, with a toolbar at the top, then when a toolbarbutton on the top left is hit the PageView slides to the right (like Path or Facebook for example), revealing a tableView.

I'm able to get either one to work separately no problem, but am struggling to have these multiple view controllers work together with the appDelegate. I've primarily been using ViewDeck: https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck for the slide out implementation, but if there's another way that would be easier to implement with a pageviewcontroller, I'm definitely open to it.

I don't really have much for code to post since I'm still just trying to figure it out conceptually.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After Edit:**

To do what you want to do, I think it's best to add the next controller as a child view controller of the page view controller (which is self.parentViewController in DataViewController).

```
#import "DataViewController.h"
#import "NextController.h"
#import "ModelController.h"

@implementation DataViewController {
    BOOL viewRevealed;
    NextController *next;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    viewRevealed = NO;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.dataLabel.text = [self.dataObject description];
}


-(IBAction)slideInController:(UIButton *) sender {
    if (viewRevealed == NO) {
        next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Blue"];
        next.view.frame = self.parentViewController.view.frame;
        [self.parentViewController addChildViewController:next];
        [self.parentViewController.view insertSubview:next.view belowSubview:self.view];
        [next didMoveToParentViewController:self.parentViewController];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
                self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                viewRevealed = YES;
                [(ModelController *)[(UIPageViewController *)self.parentViewController dataSource] setSlidOff:TRUE];
            }];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x -  self.view.frame.size.width/2 , self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [next.view removeFromSuperview];
            [next removeFromParentViewController];
            viewRevealed = NO;
            [(ModelController *)[(UIPageViewController *)self.parentViewController dataSource] setSlidOff:FALSE];
        }];
    }
}
```

This is all the code in the DataViewController. I added a couple of ivars that were necessary. In my test app, I connected the slideInController method to a double-tap gesture recognizer. Weird things would happen if you clicked or swiped while the DataView was partly on screen, so I added a BOOL property to the ModelController.h file (slidOff), and set it to FALSE in that class's init method. I then added another condition to the if statements in the two page view data source methods to check that property. When slidOff is TRUE the swipe gesture recognizers won't do anything. Here are those 2 methods in ModelController, as I modified them:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) || _slidOff) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound || _slidOff) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageData count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help rdelmar, it's appreciated. However, I'm not really sure on how to incorporate this into the default Page Based Application. I've tried to find any kind of examples of this case that I could refer to, but couldn't find any.

Comment: @user1947410, I've edited my answer to show you how to add it to the Apple page-based application template code.

Comment: Thanks a lot rdelmar, one last thing I'm wondering is that when the next view slides in (I set it to then slide in only a third of the screen width) is that the DataViewController then pops back in front of the NextController. Is there a way to get the DataView to stay underneath of the NextView? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Did you use the code that's posted now or the code I originally posted? I changed it because I initially misread your question. I'm asking because the code above doesn't slide in next view -- it slides out the DataView to reveal next view, which is stationary underneath. When you have both views partially visible, do you want both controllers to be usable, or just the next controller?

Comment: I used your updated code, and I believe you understood correctly. I'd like the Data View to slide over about a third of the screen revealing the Next View underneath, the Data View when partially visible doesn't need to be usable, but it would be great if when tapped, it would slide back to it's original position. Thanks!

Comment: @user1947410, I edited my code to make it do what I think you want. It required adding the next controller as a child view controller, and disabling the swipe gesture recognizers on the page view controllers while the page was partially off screen.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your help and effort and also the explanations! Cheers!